# Asks about how to find the corresponding value on another sheet and print the result

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        
// VLOOKUP target
   var targetSheetValues = ss.getSheetByName('target');
   var inRow = 3;
   var keyColumn = 6++;
   var valueColumn = 2;
   var inData = sheet3.getRange(inRow, keyColumn, sheet3.getLastRow(), valueColumn).getValues();
   var inDic = {};
   
   // key, value array save
   for(var i = 0; i < inData.length; i++) {
     inDic[inData[i][keyColumn-1]] =inData[i][valueColumn-1];
   }
   
   // input setup
   var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('input');
   var startRow = 2;
   var targetColumn = 1;
   var setColumn = 3;
   var lastRow = input.getLastRow();
   var targetValue;
   var setValue;
                                                   
   for(startRow ; startRow <= lastRow; startRow++){
                                                           
   targetValue = input.getRange(startRow,targetColumn).getValue();
   setValue = inDic[targetValue];                                 
   input.getRange(startRow,setColumn).setValue(setValue);         
   }

  
  var d = new Date(); 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange("B2:C2");

  range.setValue(d);   

}
```

I want to find the date that matches the'target date' in the'target sheet' and load the values ​​of the multiple ranges into the'current sheet'. I wrote a script similar to vlookup, but I need help because it is difficult to find the original solution.

[image]

Comment: The most obvious problem that I see with just taking a glance at your code is a bad use of [`setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) vs [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues). Could you maybe share a sample sheet with an example avoiding all sensitive information?

Comment: Your code is incomplete sheet3 is undefined and this kind of assignment is not very smart `var keyColumn = 6++;` It makes me wonder if you know what your doing.  Assuming Sheet3 was defined globally then its unlikely that the number of rows in this expression is correct. `var inData = sheet3.getRange(inRow, keyColumn, sheet3.getLastRow(), valueColumn).getValues();`  You might want to reread [mcve]